# Cython: call Python function from inside prange()

Tags: python, multithreading, cython, gil

### The problem

I am trying to implement a threaded chunk manager for my game. But it gives the error:

```
f:\PyCraft\helpers\terrain_generator_helper.pyx:6:12: target may not be a Python object as we don't have the GIL
```

I am new to cython, so expect bugs in my code. I am on windows 10.

### The code

```
import random
from cython.parallel import  prange

cdef func_exec(func):
    with nogil:
        for n in prange(0, 1):
            with gil:
                func()

def _start_generaion(world):
    random_index = world._queue[random.randint(0, len(world._queue) - 1)]
    world.all_chunks[random_index].generate()
    world._queue.remove(random_index)

def start_generaion(world):
    func_exec(lambda: _start_generaion(world))
```

### Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try typing the loop variable `n`

Comment: I did `cdef int n` before `with nogil:` and it worked! Thanks!